# add multiple ad groups to elasticsearch role

Tags: elasticsearch, active-directory, ldap

I am using the following command to add one ad group at a time to a role in elastic search:

```
PUT _xpack/security/role_mapping/GROUPNAME
{
    "roles" : [

      "role_name"

    ],

    "rules" : {

      "field" : {
        "groups" : "CN=cn_name,OU=ou_type,OU=ou,DC=maple,DC=dc,DC=dc,DC=dc"

      }

    },
    "enabled": true
}
```

I would like to put in a lot more groups. whats the appropriate format for this?

I tried a few variations of:

```
PUT _xpack/security/role_mapping/GROUPNAME
{
    "roles" : [
      "reader"
    ],

    "rules" : {
      "field" : [
        {
          "groups" : "INFO1"
        },
        {
          "groups" : "INFO2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "enabled": true
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was just a formatting issue:

```
PUT _xpack/security/role_mapping/GROUPNAME
{
    "roles" : [
      "reader"
    ],

    "rules" : {
      "field" :
        {
          "groups" : ["INFO1","INFO2"]
        }
    },
    "enabled": true
}
```

Put the ad info where the INFO clauses go.